# Create a number of TextViews based on Spinner selection

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I have a 3 textview and their corresponding 2 spinners and edittext. I want that when user selects "No. of times" as 3 which is string in spinner then there should be 3 textviews in the next screen

Here is a screenshot

http://postimage.org/image/vk9ngksk9/8e94a435/

Means to say if I select 2 from spinner there should be 2 textviews in the next screen.

Here is a screenshot of the next screen

http://postimage.org/image/n25axcf8x/dbb0775d/

So I want the number of textviews to correspond to the spinner selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then what you should do is parsing into the intent the selected item like so :

In your first activity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
//Here I set an ID and the value so you can find it in the second activity
i.putExtra(nbTextView, Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem());
startActivity(i);
```

In your second activity :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
nbTextView = data.getInt("nbTextView");
```

and then use this variable to dynamically create your TVs.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can get int value from spinner and save it to some global place, and then from next screen you can access that value and you can inflate textView as much as this value. Something like this:

```
View main = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
for(int i = 0; i < spinnerValue; i++) {
     TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
     tv.setText(i+". value");

     main.addView(tv);
}
```

Here's main view is wherever you want to add your textviews...

Comment: @yatya,,,let me apply this logic,,,,,the sample code u have posted i should add in my first screen.,...if possible,,,,can u post the 2 activities code,,,,,,,,I will be very thankful to you..

Comment: I didn't really get which code you want. But what you just need to do is: int spinnerValue = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem()); and you can make it static, so you'll be able to reach it from second page and you can use this as i said before...

Comment: @yahya..it works fine for textview,,,,but problem is this....after first screen,,i have screen containing a button,on that button click i want to display corresponding texts

Comment: What do u mean? You also have to have buttons as much as textViews? if so, just do the same thing with buttons as well...